# Connecting to a iOS WebDriverAgent session started by xcuitrunner on Windows

Tags: c#, ios, webdriver

I have started the Facebook/Appium WebDriverAgent on an iOS device using Quamotion xcuitrunner on a Windows PC.

I now want to create a test automation script in C# that uses this WebDriverAgent to automate a script on my iOS device.

I'm not really sure which client library I should use, and how I should connect to this session. I read I need to set the `remoteWebDriverAgentUrl` but I'm unsure about how to do so.

I've seen this WebDriver client code, but I'm unsure how I can use it to connect directly to the WebDriverAgent:

```cs
AppCapabilities capabilities = new AppCapabilities(
    deviceId: "12345678900aaa0000a00a000000a0a00a0aa0aa",
    appId: "com.company.app",
    appVersion: "0.1",
    clearApplicationSettings: false);

this.driver = new AppDriver(capabilities);
this.driver.WaitUntilReady();
```

I want to connect http://localhost:53121/session/00AAA0AA-A0A0-AA0A-0A00-AA0000A0000 using webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

The WebDriverAgent implements the WebDriver protocol, but with some twists. This means you can't use the C# WebDriver or Appium clients directly.

There's a C# client for the WebDriverAgent, named [Quamotion.Malaga](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quamotion.Malaga/), which you can use to connect to the WebDriverAgent.

You can use this client to create a script like this, with a typical application which shows a login screen:

```cs
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:53121"); // This URL will change every time you launch xcuitrunner
var driver = new WdaDriver(uri");

var response = driver.LaunchApp("your.app.id");
var emailElement = driver.FindElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeTextField");
emailElement.SendKeys("me@outlook.com");

var passwordElement = driver.FindElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeSecureTextField");
passwordElement.SendKeys("Secure!");

var signinButton = driver.FindElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeButton");
signinButton.Click();

var screenshot = driver.GetScreenshot();
screenshot.SaveAsFile("screenshot.png");
```